# Firebase Cloud Messaging: HTTP v1 API

Tags: http, firebase-cloud-messaging, postman, google-apis-explorer

I am trying to send push notifications from firebase cloud messaging HTTP v1 API, not understanding how to send using postman with OAuth 2 token.
Please explain how to use this API in postman to send notifications using OAuth 2 token.

Comment: What is the problem? How does your test request look like ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a POST request, but will require you authentication with the service credentials first. easiest way is with a node app with the following:

```js
var {google} = require('googleapis');
var MESSAGING_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging';
var SCOPES = [MESSAGING_SCOPE];
function getAccessToken() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var key = require('./service-account.json');
        var jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
            key.client_email,
            null,
            key.private_key,
            SCOPES,
            null
        );
    }
}
```

1. Enter request URL as `https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<your-project-id>/messages:send`
   With Headers `'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accesstoken`

Setting-up with POSTMAN
`Body > raw > JSON (application/json)` and add following code:

```js
{
    "message": {
        "token": "FCM_TOKEN",
        "data": {
            "body": "Body of Your Notification in data",
            "title": "Title of Your Notification in data",
            "key_1": "Value for key_1",
            "key_2": "Value for key_2"
        }
    }
}
```

However, if you want to skip all the hassle: Firebase has a built-in FCM Tool that allows you to send manual notifications [**HERE**](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/notification/compose)